# Truncate comments after closing HTML tag using BASH

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out how to strip content after the closing HTML tag **using only bash or common GNU tools**. For example, given the following HTML template, what would be an efficient way to remove the trailing comment without touching the embedded comment and not using an external language such as Python?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site | Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Don't delete me! -->

</body>
</html>

<!--
Man, I really wish to vanish!
-->
```

The only thing I can come up with is to read the whole file into memory and process it there, i.e. something archaic as getting the location of the closing HTML tag with regex magic, truncating thereafter, and writing back out to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `sed`:

```
sed -n '1,/<\/html>/p' some.html > truncated.html
```

### Example:

```
% sed -n '1,/<\/html>/p' some.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site | Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Don't delete me! -->

</body>
</html>
```

### Where:

- `-n`  -- suppress automatic printing of pattern space
- `1` is the first line
- the line containing '`</html>`' is the last line
- `p` prints these lines

Comment: We can use `-i` option instead of `> to file`. Though you may have avoided it for portability.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/<\/html>/q' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Do whatever it is you need to do with the resulting variable.

```
myFile="whatever_your_filename_is.something"
ProcessedText=$( sed 's:\(.\+</html>\).*:\1:' $myFile )
```

What this does is: pipe the content of the file to `sed`, which then looks for a string with maximum length ending in  and captures this. The rest of the text is matched, but not captured. This (i.e. the complete text) is then replaced by the captured text (i.e. everything up to and including the  tag).

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1,/<\/html>/' file
```

Comment: Or even just... `awk '1,/<\/html>/' file`, which makes this shorter than my `sed` solution (but not as short as @potong's).